# something on top of core data lightweight migration

Tags: ios, core-data, migration

I have an Album entity in model 5, in model 6 I added a "favoriteTracksCount" attribute with a default value 0, so this is a case when i should use a lightweight migration. But there is one issue though.
So in both model 5 and model 6 there was a Track entity with a BOOL attribute "favorite".
So when the light weight migration is completed, I want to set an appropriate value to favoriteTracksCount. And this is crucial for correct functioning of the app, so it needs to be done before anyone can use persistentStoreCoordinator.
So I can detect whether I need a migration:

```
NSDictionary *sourceMetadata = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:NSSQLiteStoreType URL:storeURL error:&error];
    NSManagedObjectModel *destinationModel = [_persistentStoreCoordinator managedObjectModel];
    BOOL pscCompatibile = [destinationModel isConfiguration:nil compatibleWithStoreMetadata:sourceMetadata];
    NSLog(@"Migration needed? %d", !pscCompatibile);
```

and even know how to detect which entities were added/removed

But how can I find out which attributes were added to the existing entity? (this is important, because it could be a migration from version 4 to 5 for instance)

So what  I want to do is let it perform lightweight migration, make sure it has migrated to model 6 and perform a fetchrequest for every album to find out how many favorite tracks it has and save this number to favoriteTracksCount.
And the second question is if it's the right approach I chose, or it's better to user manual migration in my case?
Thanks